# How to get to network manipulation setting in macOS ventura?

Tags: network, permission

When I install and run [GYBooster](https://file.gybooster.com/file/6242c4c99781de6b205ccce6R5oDEkiS02/attachment/GYBooster-macOS-1.0.0(58).dmg), it asked for a permission which I have granted. Now I want to revoke the permission and I cannot find where it is. I tried uninstalling GYBooster and reinstalling it again to see the permission popup but apparently removing the app does not automatically revoke the permission thus the popup was not shown.

Comment: "asked for a permission" - which permission?

Comment: @Tetsujin i forgot, otherwise i could probably find the setting myself.

Comment: @Tetsujin if u install the app u will see what permission it is asking, and perhaps u can take a screenshot and upload it here as an answer.

Comment: @Tetsujin i think it's the network manipulation but probably it is called something else.

Comment: That doesn't look like the kind of app I would go anywhere near, sorry. I don't install anything I can't read.

Comment: @Tetsujin understandable